# Why I can't execute this terminal comand in my php code?

Tags: php

i want to test via ApacheBenchmark a website, and,after the execution, people.txt contains just sh: 1: ab: not found

i tried full path of ApacheBenchmark

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ab -k -c 350 -n 20000 www.yahoo.com 2>&1');
$file = 'people.txt'; 
file_put_contents($file, $output);
?>
```

Comment: Uhmm.. `ab` not found. What's the problem? Ask yourself, what is ab, and is it in your path?

Comment: ab is ApacheBenchmark and i found my path with which command

Comment: Just do `dir` in your `shell_exec()` and see if it works

Comment: i tried   
$output = shell_exec('/usr/sbin/ab -k -c 350 -n 20000 www.yahoo.com 2>&1');
and my output is sh: 1: /usr/sbin/ab: not found (mac 10.14.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have "ab" tool installed on your system. If you're on Debian based OS (e.g. Ubuntu), use `apt-get install apache2-utils` to install it. For RedHat systems, try `yum install httpd-tools`

Comment: if i write "ab" comand in my terminal it display the usage information

Comment: In that case you can do `which ab` to find the full path, and use that in shell_exec() call